# Iot central and TPM provisioning

Tags: azure, tpm, azure-iot-central

Can a Device with a TPM Chip be connected to Iot central using a TPM Chip? 
If so how? I can not find any docu. I only see SAS and certificate.

It should be also possible to add an enrollment in the dps

Comment: Hi was the proposed answer useful? If so please accept it so others can benefit from it.

Comment: I see the answer was unaccepted. Please do let me know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IoT Central doesn't support TPM at this time. Because you can't configure the DPS that IoT Central uses, you can't use a TPM module the way you would with your own IoT Hub.

Answer (score 0):

For future travellers, IoT central now supports TPM.

As per this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#create-individual-enrollments

Comment: The link kindly provided by [Philip Fourie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11123/philip-fourie) is now broken, but regarding the Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service (DPS) and support for TPM, the updated documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-manage-enrollments#create-a-tpm-individual-enrollment See also how to provision with a simulated TPM in this more [detailed guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-tpm?pivots=programming-language-ansi-c#create-a-device-enrollment-entry)